# How to maintain module level translation files with react-native-localize?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented react-native-localize in one of my applications and currently working fine. I followed the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localize url for implementation. React-native && react-native-localize is pretty new for me.

I would like to understand that, which is an advisable way to maintain language specific files(en or ar).

- **Option-1** is to maintain single en.json across the application. Which will contains all module level language translations
  Example: **en.json**

{
"hometitle": "Home Page",
"plptitle": "PLP Title"

}

- **Option-2** is to maintain module level language translations like homepage_en.json, plppage_en.json, Is this possible, etc?

File one -
**homepage_en.json**

{
"title": "Home Page"
},

File two-
**plppage_en.json**

```
 {
        "title": "Product Page"
    }
```

2. Another question which i have,  is that possible to have nested JSON inside en.json with this react-native-localize library? Example:

{
"homepage": {
"title": "Home Page"
},
"plppage": {
"title": "Product Page"
}
}

Kindly provide inputs based on your project experience.

Comment: All three are valid I guess. In a recent project, I have used the 1st method i.e. all translations were in one en.json file. Keeping translation in module wise files like homepage_en.json or plppage_en.json will make sense if your project very large. You should go with 1st or 2nd method.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Rishikesh. When using all translations in one en.json. what all problem you had faced. That may help us. And even in single file approach. Did you tried  nesting JSON in en.json? or flat JSON structure? How you differentiated your modules. ?

Comment: I haven't nested JSON. I've kept simple because my app was small. My JSON file length was not more than 100 lines. I haven't face any problem.